# Insert Output data into a new table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1292

I want to insert output of the query but i am not able to insert the output i am getting error as ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_Name (1292) - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Null'

```
insert into grid SELECT
  (CASE
  WHEN sample.Airtel = 'Null' THEN'0'
  WHEN sample.Airtel <'1000' THEN '1'
  WHEN sample.Airtel >'2933' THEN '3'
ELSE '2'
  END) AS airtel1,

  ( CASE
  WHEN sample.Jio = 'Null' THEN'0'
  WHEN sample.Jio <'1000' THEN '1'
  WHEN sample.Jio >'2933' THEN '3'
ELSE '2'
  END )AS jio1,

  ( CASE
  WHEN sample.Vodaidea = 'Null' THEN'0'
  WHEN sample.Vodaidea <'1000' THEN '1'
  WHEN sample.Vodaidea >'2933' THEN '3'
ELSE '2'
  END )AS voda1,

  ( CASE
  WHEN sample.Airtel_count = 'Null' THEN'0'
  WHEN sample.Airtel_count >'32' THEN 'High'
  WHEN sample.Airtel_count <='1' THEN 'Low'
ELSE 'Mid'
  END) AS airtelgrid,

    ( CASE
  WHEN sample.Jio_count = 'Null' THEN'0'
  WHEN sample.Jio_count >'32' THEN 'High'
  WHEN sample.Jio_count <='1' THEN 'Low'
ELSE 'Mid'
  END) AS jiogrid,

   (  CASE
  WHEN sample.VodaIdea_count = 'Null' THEN'0'
  WHEN sample.VodaIdea_count >'32' THEN 'High'
  WHEN sample.VodaIdea_count <='1' THEN 'Low'
ELSE 'Mid'
  END) AS vodagrid,

  sample.*
FROM
  sample
```

the table definition is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `grid` (
  `Hex_id` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Airtel` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Airtel_count` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Jio` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Jio_count` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Vodaidea` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VodaIdea_count` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `airtel1` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jio1` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `voda1` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `airtelgrid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jiogrid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vodagrid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

the sample table definition is as follows:

CREATE TABLE `sample` (
      `Hex_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
      `Airtel` int(50) NOT NULL,
      `Airtel_count` int(50) NOT NULL,
      `Jio` int(50) NOT NULL,
      `Jio_count` int(50) NOT NULL,
      `Vodaidea` int(50) NOT NULL,
      `VodaIdea_count` int(50) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: Are you storing null as a string?  Sample data as text int the question would help clarify.

Comment: Please do some background reading into the difference between a string and a number. This query is full of instances where you compare a number with a string-that-contains-digits/store a string-that-contains-digits in an number by implicit conversion; never a wise idea and there’s no need for it if you’re just a bit more careful when writing code

Comment: The syntax for insert select is incorrect it should be insert into select (column list) select columns (no as statement) from etc and the inclusion of sample * is just wrong you should review the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html